# Do Ghasts spawn near portals in the overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

We often hear that ghasts (bunny-ears) "sometimes" spawn near portals in the "real world"; but I can't for the life of me remember having seen any actual evidence of this being true.

Do ghasts actually spawn near portals? Or is this another myth like Herobrine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Ghast&oldid=106006)

> Notch added a small chance for Ghasts to spawn in the Overworld near Portals in Beta 1.5. A Ghast spawned outside of the Nether will fly everywhere, mainly above the clouds. Can even spawn extremely rarely without a portal.

[Notch's actual confirmation](http://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/28442542287)

Comment: I'm tempted to go with "That's not an answer, as it more or less confirms the base assumption of the question: 'We often hear that ghasts (bunny-ears) spawn near portals.'", but that would be crass.

Comment: Here is a link to the youtube video that that comment cites: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cDgCPDKq5o&t=15m25s

Comment: @Williham - I feel like a wiki article is more reliable than hearsay, but you're right nonetheless.  I added Notch's actual twitter comment on the subject.

Comment: @Origami - that comment is dated in October, which implies much earlier than 1.5 - ever since their addition in the Halloween update, most likely.

Comment: @Raven - From what I have read, it has always happened, but before 1.5 it was due to a bug and now it is official.

Comment: @Raven: The video fades out for a second, and when it comes back a ghast has materialized directly where he was staring.  Seems legit to me.

Answer (score 6):

This is my understanding of the situation:

- Notch *planned* to have ghasts spawning near portals, before the Halloween update.
- It was not actually implemented in the Halloween update or any later one.

I believe the latter has been found to be the case by those who have studied the code of Minecraft, but I don't have a citation handy. Minecraft Forums would be the place to look for one.

Comment: As a modder I've decompiled the game for its source code, I'll take a quick look around to confirm this. I will agree though that I do not THINK that this would have been added. The only cases I can remember ghasts getting into the overworld is through oversized portals or spawn eggs.

Answer (score 1):

they can't spawn in overworld, but they can get to overworld through portals if you built it 4x4 or bigger!!! .. making a security caution of building 4x4 nether portals so they can destroy your wooden house if they attacked you inside it.

Answer (score -2):

It can spawn if the portal is at least 4x4 blocks high. While extremely rare, they can also spawn without a portal.